# API not resolving on own site

Tags: php, xml, nginx

We have an API available.  It's working fine for a number of apps and websites.  Now I'm rebuilding our mobile site to utilize this API.

If I hit the API on our dev server from the mobile site, I get results.

But as soon as I'm in production, ish hits the fan.  The curl call times out.  Now if I try an external API, the curl call works just fine.  But as soon as we plug in our API URL, nothing.

I'm not sure if I'm posting this in the right area, but I figured it's worth a shot.  Any ideas on what is occurring?

Comment: So the difference between the dev server and production server is what?  Need more details about network topology and relationship to mobile site.  Is the mobile site simply an app, a webapp, what?

Comment: Mobile site is simply m.domain.com, optimized for mobile browsers.  We have two dev servers.  One on the same network as the production servers.  The other is a local server I run in my basement.  Same specs as the production servers.  As soon as I'm on domain.com calling domain.com/api, it no longer works.  But if I'm on domain2.com calling domain.com/api it will work.

Comment: check your http logs for errors. also ensure that calls aren't getting dropped due to Cross Domain rules. You need to provide more details on your error

Comment: You could create a ServerAlias (or nginx equivalent) in production, api.domain.com and see if things work that way.  Are these javascript AJAX calls bombing out or are you going PHP to PHP over HTTP?  If that's the case I'd almost vote for the new domain just for sake of separation.  1. It should be easier to move the api later that way.  2. If external code doesn't need to hit the API, consider running api.domain.com on 127.0.0.1 or LAN IP as well.